# Adding a JTable with data to a JDialog

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I am trying to display a JTable with data from a database. My code has a submit button and when I hit that the data has to appear in the table.

To create the application, I created a "New JDialog" using NetBeans and starting placing some components like text boxes along with the submit button. I then added a Panel to it and then added a JTable inside of the panel.

In my code, I have a method for the Default table model which returns a default table model object. As part of the submit button's event handling code, I am passing the default table model's object into the JTable component (just using _table = new JTable(default table model object). _table was declared by NetBeans when I added the table to my form.

How should I proceed and get my table to display data? NetBeans basically creates the code. Technically:

1) My class extends JDialog and then comes the constructor which takes a frame and boolean as input.
2) The initcomponents method comes in the constructor.
3) I have my methods and then the event handling code.
4) The main method contains the invoke later with a runnable object and the run method which instantiates a JDialog object and sets it to true.

If the explanation is not clear and I should post the code, please let me know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm assuming that `_table` was created by the netbeans form editor and that it is a reference to the table which is on the screen.  So instead of using `_table = new JTable(...)`, you should be using `_table.setModel(model)`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you sir! One quick question though. I only see four columns, how can see all the columns and adjust the column width to display the entire column for all of the columns. Please post your response as a reply and I will mark it as the correct answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that _table was created by the netbeans form editor and that it is a reference to the table which is on the screen. So instead of using `_table = new JTable(...)`, you should be using `_table.setModel(model)`

> I only see four columns, how can see all the columns and adjust the column width to display the entire column for all of the columns

Wrap the `JTable` in a `JScrollPane`...

See [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) and [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Comment: Quick question again please. When I created the table in NetBeans, there was a Scroll Pane associated with it. How should I now display the scroll pane after adding the table to it?

Comment: If the `JTable` is already wrapped in a `JScrollPane`, then do nothing.  Make sure that the  `JTable`'s `autoResizeMode`  is not set to `AUTO_RESIZE_OFF`

Comment: OK. I am not specifically adding anything to JScrollPane. The autoReszieMode is not set to AUTO_RESIZE_OFF. However, all the columns don't get displayed and the column names still get truncated. I see the vertical scroll bar though. What should I do? Thanks again!

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: To explain the problem better, I created a JTable and there is a ScrollPane that comes with it. However, when I use the set model method, each column has the same width. The horizontal scroll pane is missing. What I would like to do is to have the full column header displayed and have the horizontal scrollbar facilitating the column navigation. If you would still like me to post the code, I can format it and get it up here. However, the code I have is pretty easy. I am not using any specific layout. Should I change any of the ScrollPane properties?